# Why the if doesn't do the comparison?

Tags: php, file, comparison

I'm trying to compare two numbers through an if statement, but it doesn't work.
One number comes from a database in a .txt file.

This is the database where the number comes from:

```
Number of registrations: 64
50|name|surname|email|12412412
61|name|surname|email|07802634202
```

This is the script :

```
$phone = "07802634202";

// Get th file from the database and convert it in an array
$database = file("database.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
// Get the lenght of the database "Rows"
$database_length = count($database);

// Transform  in an array the string inside each row and save them in a variable 
for($a = 1; $a < $database_length; $a++) {

  $data[$a] = explode("|", $database[$a]);
}

// Check if the last variable 'Number' in a row is equal to $phone 
foreach($data as $key => $val) {

  echo "Database val: " . $val[4];
  echo "Phone val: " . $phone;
  // If it's equal print yep otherwise nope
  if ($val[4] == $phone) { 

    echo "\n yep \n"; 
  } else { 

    echo "\n nope \n";
  }
}
```

This is what the console prints:

```
Database val: 12412412                                                                                                                                          
Phone val: 07802634202                                                                                                                                          
 nope                                                                                                                                                           
Database val: 07802634202                                                                                                                                       
Phone val: 07802634202                                                                                                                                          
 nope
```

Please if something is not clear, just let me know. I've tried everything without any results.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Side note: I hope those aren't actual email addresses. Edit: which have now been removed.

Comment: Is there a special reason you're not using *only* a database for this?

Comment: Could be worth throwing `trim()` in there  - `if (trim($val[4]) == trim($phone)) { `

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry I realize it late, I've changed them. I'm learning PHP so I'm making a simple database from scratch to improve my skills.

Comment: try a `var_dump($val[4]); var_dump($phone)` instead of echos... to validate data types and content. What is displayed?

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks a lot!. I've just use `trim()` in `$val[4])` and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your data is from various sources, it's always worth [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)ming the fields to ensure any leading or trailing spaces are removed.

```
if (trim($val[4]) == trim($phone)) {...}
```

Just a slight addition, worth adding `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` to the call to [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) as otherwise you will end with with the new line at the end of the line.